# Excel - Return value that is in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to have a formula that returns the correct value for a range.

Minimum Square footage per bed = 300 (This number may change so formula needs to take this into account  and  not be just a fixed number)

Maximum Square footage per bed = 600 (This number may change so formula needs to take this into account  and  not be just a fixed number)

There is a calculation to calculate the square footage per bed.

i.e. 40,000 square feet / 100 beds = 400 square feet per bed  (Cell needs to compare to the minimum value and maximum value and see if it falls between those values and return the 400 square feet per bed since it falls between those amounts.

i.e. 10,000 square feet / 100 beds = 100 square feet per bed  (Cell needs to compare to the minimum value and maximum value and see if it falls between those values and return the 300 square feet per bed since it falls below the minimum.

i.e. 100,000 square feet / 100 beds = 1,000 square feet per bed  (Cell needs to compare to the minimum value and maximum value and see if it falls between those values and return the value of  600 square feet per bed since it is above the maximum.

Any help would be appreciate!  Have a great day!  Ron Howard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A little MAX a big MIN

[image: formula output]

`=IFERROR(MAX($A$2,MIN($B$2,A4/B4)),"")`

- The minimum amount goes in the MAX function and maximum amount goes in the MIN function
- `$A$2` absolute address of minimum amount cell
- `$B$2` absolute address of maximum amount cell

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick response.  Have a great week!  Ron